# Flutter - App Store Connect rejection due to needing "functional link to the Terms of Use (EULA)" in "your app's binary"

Tags: flutter, app-store-connect

Our flutter app, with a subscription membership in-app-purchase, is repeatedly being rejected by [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/) for the following reason :

> Specifically, we were unable to find the following required
> information in your app's binary:
>
> – A functional link to the Terms of Use (EULA)

How do we update the app's binary to have a link to the EULA ?
Does anyone know what this message actually means ?

Note that we do show the EULA when the user first enters the app, and there is link to it - so this message doesn't appear to be about the actual functioning/UI in the app.

Note that this is a **Flutter** app, so bonus points on the answer if you can tell how to set the EULA in the binary in Flutter.  ("bonus points" being an expression, I have no authority from SO to allocate extra points)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, they need a button that opens the browser on a public page that contains your Terms of Use/Privacy Policy. This button should be available at all times, not only when the user first opens the app.

You can do that using the [`url_launcher`](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package. Example:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    launch('https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en-US');
  },
  child: Text('Terms of Use'),
),
```

I have implemented this a few times and haven't had issues publishing to the App Store.

Comment: Thank you - This sounds right - I'll attempt this and mark the answer as correct if it gets us through.

Comment: @kris please tell us if the answer is correct :)

Comment: @arisalexis I don't remember - I think so.

Comment: This is answer still valid.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI iOS 14.0+ be like

```
Link("End User License Agreement", 
     destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/dev/stdeula/")!)
```